C# Retrieve a user attribute exclusively accessible from its own security context
In the context of a C# application on Windows running under an AD account, let's say UserA. I'm desperate to know if there is a way to get an attribute or information, no matter which one, belonging exclusively to UserA's security context. In other words, an attribute that can only be accessed if we are in the Windows/Ad security and authentication context of UserA.
Things like getting the user's SID aren't secure enough, because any other AD user, even non-admin, with permission to read AD could get another user's SID.
WindowsIdentity currentUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
var sid = currentUser.User.Value;

Isn't there something else, much more secure?

Maybe not exactly what you're looking for, but you can set up confidential attributes in AD: https://medium.com/beyond-the-helpdesk/easily-configure-confidential-attributes-in-active-directory-769bd2b9d12c

@TawabWakil that's very close to what I am looking for ! in fact, I perhaps hoped a little naively that there already existed certain user attributes which by default are marked as confidential, which would avoid having to do the configuration described in this article... By chance do you know is there one by default?

I don't think so. I think the default security is such that all users can read all attributes. It may be worth chatting up your AD admin to see how attribute-level security is set up at your organization, and if anything has been changed from the defaults.
